# i have one error in this code

Tags: php

i have this form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="insertartrabajo.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<legend>formato vertical</legend>
<br />
<label for="cserv">Servicio:</label>
<select name="cserv">
<option value="vacio">Seleccione un servicio</option>
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM servicios GROUP BY servicios.nombre";
$resultado=mysql_query($sql); 
while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){ 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $fila["nombre"]; ?>"><?php echo $fila["nombre"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<br>
<label for="cdirv">Direccion:</label>
<input name="cdirv" type="text">
<br>
<label for="fileField">Foto:</label>
<input type="file" name="cfotov" id="fileField">
<br>
<label for="cobserv">Observaciones:</label>
<textarea name="cobserv" cols="10" rows="3"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Insertarv" value="Insertar"/>
</form>
```

and this second archive...

```
<?php session_start(); 
include("includes/conexiones.php");
$sql="SELECT * FROM trabajos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1" ;
$resultado=mysql_query($sql);
$fila=mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
$fila["id"]=$lastid;
if ($_GET["cserv"]!=""){
$servicio=$_GET["cserv"];}
if ($_GET["cdirv"]!=""){
$direccion=$_GET["cdirv"];}
if ($_GET["cobserv"]!=""){
$observaciones=$_GET["cobserv"];}
if ($_GET["cfotov"]!=""){
$foto=$_FILES["cfotov"]["name"];
ini_set('post_max_size','100M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','100M');
ini_set('max_execution_time','1000');
ini_set('max_input_time','1000');
$fototmp=$_FILES["cfotov"]["tmp_name"];
list($ancho, $alto)=getimagesize($fototmp);
$nuevoancho=600;
$nuevoalto=600*$alto/$ancho;
$nuevaimg=imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoancho,$nuevoalto);
$idnuevaimg=imagecreatefromjpeg($fototmp);
imagecopyresized($nuevaimg,$idnuevaimg,0,0,0,0,$nuevoancho,$nuevoalto,$ancho,$alto);
imagejpeg ($nuevaimg,"imagenes/grandes/".$fotov.$lastid+1);
$fototmp=$_FILES["cfotov"]["tmp_name"]; 
list($ancho, $alto)=getimagesize($fototmp);
$nuevoancho=144;
$nuevoalto=144*$alto/$ancho;
$nuevaimg=imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoancho, $nuevoalto);
$idnuevaimg=imagecreatefromjpeg($fototmp);
imagecopyresized($nuevaimg,$idnuevaimg,0,0,0,0,$nuevoancho,$nuevoalto,$ancho,$alto);}
imagejpeg ($nuevaimg,"imagenes/peques/".$foto.$lastid+1);
$sql="INSERT INTO trabajos (servicio, direccion, observaciones, foto) VALUES ('$servicio', '$direccion', '$observaciones', '$foto')";
mysql_query($sql);
$idtrabajo=mysql_insert_id();
header("location:insertartrabajo2.php?vid=$idtrabajo");
?>
```

i have the frist problem in line 20, list($ancho, $alto)=getimagesize($fototmp);
the computer tell me this: Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in /usr/home/ibanvaquero.com/web/pruebas/inoxlan 17-12.12/insertartrabajo.php on line 20

(sorry my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your **`<form>`** method to `POST`. You can’t post files with the `GET` Method.

Change like this:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="insertartrabajo.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: That would be my next test, but that change should not be important. i like put all in GET to no have error with form and links... thank you for answer   (sorry my english)